# Are simulations a form of multi-objective optimization?

Tags: multi-objective-optimization

*Where is the line when an approach is called multi-objective optimization?* For example:

**Problem**

Presume I want to optimize an optimization problem, for example nurse rostering, with 2 soft constraints:

- Constraint A) for employee happiness: number of rejected "day off requests"
- Constraint B) for service quality: number of shifts that match the employee's affinity

Now, I don't know yet if A) is a higher priority than B) or visa versa.

**Solution**

If - instead of running an optimization to come up with a pareto front - I run a normal solver twice:

- Solve once with weights `A=1 and B=1000`
- Solve again with weights `A=1000 and B=1`

and then allow the user to pick from these two *simulations* the solution which he/she prefers.

**Question**

Would you still call this approach multi-objective solving? What does the literature say?

Comment: Are you considering "simulation" as synonymous with "single-objective optimization"? What is the fundamental difference between your "simulations" and a Pareto front that would consist of those two points plus additional similar ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a fair sized body of research in interactive multiobjective optimization, and while I'm not familiar with most of it, I think this would fit right in. Decades ago, I (vaguely) remember two of my colleagues looking at an interactive approach for multiobjective LPs, in which they would combine the criteria using a weighted sum, solve, show the individual objective values to the user, let the user adjust the weights by increasing/decreasing the importance of various criteria, solve again and iterate *ad nauseam* (meaning they would continue until the decision maker fatigued and begged them to stop). That was considered multiobjective optimization, so I assume your approach would be.

Comment: Interesting. So we've been doing multi-objective optimization for years - by playing with constraint weights and running simulations basically, but never called it that because it doesn't use a pareto front... This also answers my other question! I should have asked if anyone has ever seen pareto front optimization survive in production. :) Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 8):

***tl;dr*–**  The term you're looking for is [***sensitivity analysis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis).

---

> Would you still call this approach multi-objective solving? What does the literature say?

Trying different possible parameters to form a portfolio of options is called doing a [***sensitivity analysis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis).

For example, say you're an engineer designing a light-bulb.  You know you want it to last a long time, be power-efficient, cheap, and all that good stuff – though you don't want to make assumptions about the trade-offs between those things, e.g. if making it 1% cheaper at the cost of being 1% less efficient is a good trade or not.  Then you can do a *sensitivity-analysis*: generate a portfolio of results corresponding to various plausible trade-offs.

Comment: Good point! The approach is indeed are exactly the same as a sensitivity analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add to the existing answers the following result [1]:

Let $f_1,f_2$ be two convex differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$, and consider the corresponding multiobjective optimization problem.
Then the set of weak Pareto solutions is exactly equal to
$$ \bigcup\limits_{\alpha,\beta \geq 0} {\rm{argmin}}~\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2.$$

In other words, any minimizer of a weighted sum of your functions is a weak Pareto equilibrium, and reciprocally. If you get rid of the convexity assumption on the functions, you lose the reciproque.

In your context, it means that with your chosen weights `A` and `B`, you are choosing two specific Pareto equilibriums among all the possible ones. I would consider this to be multiobjective optimization.

[1] : Theory of vector optimization, Dinh The Luc, 1988. See Proposition IV.2.10.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this randomly. I am actually a doctoral student with a focus on interactive multiobjective methods. Typically if the constraints are soft, we can treat them as extra objective functions. Then, you definitely have a multiobjective optimization problem at hand. If you solve it with a proper method you will get a nice set of tradeoffs between constraints A and B and you will not need to change the weights over and over again.

Comment: Welcome to OR SE!